# Finding number of quantizing layers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, quantization, dct

I'm working on image processing, and I have an image that has been DCT'd and quantized for 8 x 8 blocks of the 512 x 512 matrix, now I have to find how many quantizing levels that the image has. Do I need to take the top left pixel and place it in to an array and then place this on a graph calling `hist`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`length(unique(x(:)))`, where `x` is your image array.  This is appropriate for grayscale images.

Comment: Is x the 512 x 512 full image or an 8 x 8 block contained in it? Thank you

Comment: @Stina: It's whatever you want it to be!  Your original question isn't very clear; are you trying to get the *overall* number of levels for the *overall* image, or something else?

Comment: I appreciate I'm asking about an assignment but it is a subpart and the question is: "Estimate the required number of quantization levels for DCT coecients for different values
of the quality factor". I think my vagueness in my question stems from the fact that I am unsure of what I am being asked